# Crosstalk: Change Plotly Graph on Startup

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, crosstalk

I am trying to change a `plotly` graph via `crosstalk` in my `Rmarkdown` doc. This works in principle fine, however, I want to set the dropdown to the first element on startup via `JavaScript`. This change, however, does **not** update the graph. If I run the same code once the full page is rendered, or use a delay it works.

Thus, I assume that at the point the update `JavaScript` is run, the `plotly` graph is not yet rendered. The `setTimeout` solution works, but this feels hackis. So what is the canonical way to inform `plotly/crosstalk` that the input changed?

In the gif you see that upon startup the plot shows the full range, only after changing to `b` and then to `a` updated the graph accordingly. I would like that the graph is correctly filtered already upon startup.

### Code

````r
---
title: "Delay Plotly"
date: "1 2 2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```
```{r libs}
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
```

```{r gen-data}
set.seed(1)
mdat <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:6], 6),
                   y = sample(100, 36, TRUE),
                   fill = factor(rep(rep(1:3, each = 6), 2)),
                   grp = rep(letters[1:2], each = 18),
                   id = paste0("id", 1:36),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sd <- SharedData$new(mdat, key = ~ id)

```

```{js}
$(function() {
   // set dropdown to first element
   // setTimeout(function() { // uncomment for workaround
      $('.selectized').each(function(idx, el) {
         const sel = this.selectize;
         const options = Object.keys(sel.options);
         sel.setValue(options[0]);
      });
   // }, 1000); // uncomment for workaround
})
```


```{r}
bscols(
   filter_select("grp",
                "Group:",
                sd,
                ~ grp, multiple = FALSE),
   plot_ly(sd) %>%
      add_trace(x = ~ x, y = ~ y, type = "bar", color = ~ fill,
                marker = list(line = list(color = "white", width = 1)) ## add border to see the 2 groups
                ) %>%
      layout(barmode = "stack"))
```
````

[image: Graph is not updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smoother workaround is to use the `window.onload` hook. This avoids the need to specify the timeout delay and as opposed to `$.ready` fires not once the DOM is loaded, but the whole page is ready. Exactly what I need, unless there is a dedicated hook in `plotly` for this kind of operation? `plotly_afterplot` semmed to be the right candidate. Yet again this is not available on `$.ready`

```
window.onload = function() {
   // set dropdown to first element
   $('.selectized').each(function(idx, el) {
      const sel = this.selectize;
      const options = Object.keys(sel.options);
      sel.setValue(options[0]);
   });
```